# new default acton for makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I have a Makefile which references `myprog.c`, if I don't specify a rule for `myprog.c`, make will automatically do something like `$(CC) myprog.c`.

Can I re-specify that default behavior and add new default behavior (e.g. for files ending in `myextension`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU make has a bunch of built-in implicit rules, which is how it decides it knows how to build something out of your `myprog.c`.  You can add your own implicit rules for whatever you like.  For example, the following implicit rule tells GNU make how it can produce `.out` files from `.myextension` files:

```
%.out: %.myextension
        @echo Building $@ from $<
        @# do whatever you need here...
```

Drop that into your Makefile and you'll be able to run `gmake foo.out`, or `gmake bar.out`, or whatever, as long as you have a matching `foo.myextension`, etc., without having to specify an explicit rule for every output.

Answer (score 1):

For C particular rule may look like this:

```
%.o : %.c
        rules
```

Try to apply it for your extension.

Answer (score 1):

Make has several pre-defined [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules). You can check what rules are being applied with `make -d` option.
The default rule is

```
%: %.o    # Link object file
      $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
%.o: %.c  # Compile C source code
      $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c
```

You can redefile the implecit rules. Check [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) to do it.

Comment: You can also remove all the implicit rules, so make will clearly tell you if it can't build something, instead a silently assuming some facts. See stackoverflow.com/questions/4122831/#4126617

Answer (score 1):

Recipes for implicit rules are internally defined through variables like `COMPILE.c`, `LINK.c`, etc.

From [Catalogue of Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) chapter of GNU Make Manual:

> `make` follows the convention that the rule to compile a *.x* source file uses the variable `COMPILE.x`. Similarly, the rule to produce an executable from a *.x* file uses `LINK.x`; and the rule to preprocess a *.x* file uses `PREPROCESS.x`.

The above link also contains some predefined implicit recipes.